# CSS positioning images inside div

Tags: css

how do I position n images inline inside a div even if the div is to small for all image to fit inside, I want the ones that don't fit to go underneath the div margin and dissapear.
For example, I have:

```
<div id="container">
<img1>
<img2>
<img3>
<img4>
<img5>
.... n -images
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This will hide anything that goes outside the container element. Do note that some browsers could still allow the user to scroll in the hidden part, although that shouldn't happen on desktop browsers.

Comment: but one more question, the images are still breaking when the div ends, and they begin a new line, how do I make them stay in the same line and not break ?

Comment: In my experience, removing the spaces between the `<img>` elements helps. Since an image is an inline element, spaces affect its behavior. By not using spaces, you won't allow it to wrap to a new line, just like a long word won't be broken into two pieces.

Comment: still won't stay inline, they break at the end of the div. Maybe if I specify 'display:inline-block'  to the img ?